# Grand canonical partition function for Bose-Einstein statistic and Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics for indistinguishable particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, identical-particles

If we have N non-interacting particles and N assumes the values 1 and 2.They can be found in three energy levels $\epsilon_{l}=\epsilon*l$ with l = 0, 1, 2. I tried to write the function as Z(µ, T)=$\sum_N$ $(z^{\mu\beta})^N*Z(N,T)$.

Z(N=1,T)=1+$e^{-\beta\epsilon}$+$e^{-2\beta\epsilon}$ and Z(N=2,T)=1+$e^{-\beta\epsilon}$+$e^{-2\beta\epsilon}$+$e^{-3\beta\epsilon}$ +$e^{-4\beta\epsilon}$

Because off all possible configurations to place the particles on three different levels with no restrictions.

What is now the difference between Bose-Einstein statistic and Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics for indistinguishable particles?

I know there is a way to write it as $\prod_{l=1}Z_{\epsilon_l}$ but i want to try it that way.